# Eclipse java IDE - method undefined quick fix only proposing casting

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started programming with the latest Eclipse version: Luna.

It has annoyed me since then that the only quick fix solutions for a method being undefined is to cast the object in question to Object. Apparantly, this only happens if the class is generic.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think past versions of eclipse used to always foresee the 'create method X' solution.

Here's an example:

```
public class Test<T> {

    public Test(OtherTest test) {
        test.asdf(this);
    }

public class OtherTest {}
```

[image]

Is there a setting or something that is causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: " to cast the object in question" What do you mean? If a type `x=asd();`  Eclipse suggest to create the method `asd`

Comment: So what is the code with which this problem is reproducible?

Comment: Just added an example.

Comment: Why the -1 by the way?

Comment: I would suggest providing more information/code on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems in the constructor of `Test<T>`. From within the constructor, you are passing `this` which isn't fully created then. try changing it to something else:

```
public Test(OtherTest test) {
        test.asdf(1);
}
```

And you will get the option to create method and when clicked it does as follows:

```
public class OtherTest {
    public void asdf(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```